# Problem with getting rid of specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning

I have big dataset that has the next columns:

```
cols=['plant', 'time','date','hour','NDVI','Treatment','Line','397.01', '398.32', '399.63', '400.93', '402.24', '403.55'...,'1005']
```

I want to create new database which will contain the 7 first columns, then skip 10 and then have all the others.

I have done something like this:

```
df2=df_plants.iloc[:,10:]
df2.head()
```

but this cut the first columns and I need them as well.

I friend had reccomend me to do something like this:

```
#convert the ''numeric'' columns into float

float_cols = [float(i) for i in df_plants.columns.tolist()[4:] if type(i)==str]
df_plants.columns.values[4:] = float_cols


#detector edges removal
idx1 = (np.abs(df_plants.loc[:,float_cols].columns.values - 420))
#np.argmin(idx1)
idx2 = np.argmin(np.abs(df_plants.loc[:,float_cols].columns.values - 1005.0))
```

but when I apply it nothing happen and also i'm not sure I understand his idea in the detector edge part.

My end goal is to create new database that will contain the next columns:
plant.line.treatment.time and then all the numeric columns that are greater than 410 .

**Edit:** the best thing for me is if I could tell python somehow that if in a numerical column there are negative values, remove it.

Comment: So idea is testing values >410, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think betetr here is convert values to numeric and filter by mask:

```
cols=['plant', 'time','date','hour','NDVI','Treatment','Line',
      '397.01', '398.32', '399.63', '400.93', '402.24', '403.55','1005']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

---

```
num = pd.to_numeric(df.columns, errors='coerce')

df = df.loc[:, (num > 410) | num.isna()]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [plant, time, date, hour, NDVI, Treatment, Line, 1005]
Index: []
```

If want also converting values to numeric:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return x

df = df.rename(columns=f)

def comp(x):
    try:
        return x > 410
    except:
        return True


df = df.loc[:, df.columns.map(comp)]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [plant, time, date, hour, NDVI, Treatment, Line, 1005.0]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using slicing:

```
cols = df_plants.columns.tolist()
df2=df_plants[cols[:7] + cols[17:]]
df2.columns = pd.to_numeric(df2.columns.tolist(), errors='ignore')
```

Comment: `+` with Index objects does not concatenate the arrays, so this is not correct.

Comment: @cs95 Better???

Comment: It is but I'd rather you... nit: split this into two lines, the first one converts the headers to a list, the second line is what you already have, but becomes simpler.

Comment: it worked but can you explain why to it needs to be converted into list ? (i'm a very beginner)

Comment: `cols = [*df_plants] # python >= 3.5`

Comment: @Reut Because without converting, the original type sequences couldn't be added, don't forget to accept and upvote if it works later

Comment: @Reinstate Monica  and is there any chance that bu changing it now i'm changing the type of the column? because I suppose to run more calculations and now I get key error

Comment: @Reut - check another answer.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica now it gets error ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 17:02

Comment: @Reut Edited again

Comment: still getting key error

Comment: @Reut Edited again

Comment: now it has the same problem+ the slicing doesn't work, if  change the 17 to another number